# Need help to copy the contents of the temp file created by another shell script within a shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a shell script `test.sh`.

Within that I am trying to execute another shell script `abc.sh`.
When `abc.sh` is executed it takes in one of the options **a**,**b**,**c**.
If I choose **a** and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, it creates a temp file and opens it and if I give **q** it quits from the screen and deletes the temp file.

But when I call `test.sh`, it calls `abc.sh` and the temp file is opened.

I want to copy the temp file to home dir created by `abc.sh`, press <kbd>q</kbd> so that it exits from the script and continues with `test.sh`.

The constraint is **I am not allowed** to modify `abc.sh`.

`abc.sh` has the logic to create the temp file and on completion i.e if I hit the <kbd>q</kbd> key and it exits out of the script it and deletes the temp file as well.

I am stuck at this point within `test.sh`

```
echo a | /home/amy/abc.sh
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Here is the output from my screen where it creates an temp file

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

S1012852TB00N020405000000wwww6800001PB084Kpb474F7ED028BE71024744F07FC1EEECA667E511581D7AF6AD84E08B0040665415D32CC5ECCC900641
**/tmp/xxyyzz.2578098**
```

Is there a way to copy the files? Threading perhaps..

Comment: can you post contents of of your abc.sh script?

Comment: I recommend posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please [edit] the question to add details.

Comment: I have added some more information. Let me know if it helps

Comment: try this: `touch /tmp/reference_file; { echo a; sleep 1; find /tmp -type f -newer /tmp/reference_file -exec cp "{}" ~ \; 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2); } | ./abc.sh; rm /tmp/reference_file;`

Comment: You might use `timeout  2 ./abc.sh;` to force to quit `abc.sh` so your script can move on.

Comment: Thank you, touch /tmp/reference_file; { echo a; sleep 1; find /tmp -type f -newer /tmp/reference_file -exec cp "{}" ~ \; 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2); } | ./abc.sh; rm /tmp/reference_file; ------ using this I am able to copy it to the home directory but unable to quit it, the tmp file is still open

Comment: timeout 2 ./abc.sh; works well.. however it is creating a junk file in the region I am trying to run it 

-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxx     xxxxx     310 Aug 20 11:04 ▒

Comment: You  can simply use `if` ... `else` statment for your parameter, would be easier, or store your input inside a var, and call it like `./abc.sh $var`

Comment: he says he cannot change `abc.sh`

Comment: @RoVo the `if` ... `else` statement is for `test.sh`, in order to call `./abc.sh a` for example, same for `./abc.sh $var`

Comment: what makes you think `abc.sh` will accept arguments ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ref_file=$(mktemp)
{
  echo a
  sleep 1
  find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -newer $ref_file -exec cp "{}" ~ \; 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2)
} | timeout 2 ./abc.sh
rm $ref_file
```

You said `abc.sh` creates a junk file in "the region" you are running it.
Remove it using something like this (put before `rm $ref_file`).

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newer $ref_file -rm
```

**Explanation**:

1. Create a reference file
2. Spawn a script sequence or a subshell that is piping to `abc.sh` with `{` or `(`
3. `echo` a, b or c
4. Wait until `abc.sh` created the temp file
5. Find files newer than the reference file within  `/tmp` and move or copy it to the destination.
6. Close the script sequence / subshell with `}`or `)`
7. Pipe to abc.sh, use `timeout` to automatically kill `abc.sh` after you moved your file
8. Remove the reference file.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I had just one more update on it. timeout is not similar to quit isnt it. So, the temp file created by abc.sh is not getting deleted from the temp region coz timeout is killing the script without quitting it.